# Redirection through json_encode in php

Tags: php, json, redirect

```
if ($this->register($email, $register_status))
                    {
                        $this->sendConfirmationEmail($email);
                        echo json_encode(array("message" => $this->error = $this->l('Your email was registered. Thank You!'),"code" => 1));
                        die();
                    }
```

this is my code and I want to redirect the page after executing this code

Comment: just use `header("Location: your_page.php");` before `die()` function !! where is the issues

Comment: its showing error
XMLHttpRequest cannot load (https://www.abc./). No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin ('https://dev1.abc.') is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: check this post it may be helpful `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource`

Answer (score 0):

just use header("Location: your_page.php"); before die();

```
if ($this->register($email, $register_status))
     {
$this->sendConfirmationEmail($email);
echo json_encode(array("message" => $this->error = $this->l('Your email was registered. Thank You!'),"code" => 1));
header("Location: your_page.php");
die();
                        }
```

if error

add fist line toppage

```
    <?php 
ob_start();
    if ($this->register($email, $register_status))
         {
    $this->sendConfirmationEmail($email);
    echo json_encode(array("message" => $this->error = $this->l('Your email was registered. Thank You!'),"code" => 1));
    header("Location: your_page.php");
    die();
                            }?>
```